# Can I reuse panels\figures within a figure in GUIDE, Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm writing a matlab GUI and I want to display a panel with some lists and text fields in two different locations with different content.

Can I somehow create the panel separately and then incorporate it into the main figure more than once? or maybe create a 'child' figure?

Comment: can you not create two different panels? Do you need to reuse the lists and text fields?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this programatically. Write a script (or better a class) that creates a uipanel and adds the components you want shown in the uipanel.  You can set the Parent property of the uipanel to place it into the figure/GUI. The Matlab documentation on building a GUI programatically will be helpful.

You may want to store the references to the uipanel and other components somewhere or use the Tag property to tag them to find them later.

Then either in a callback that makes the uipanel "visible", or in the figure constructor code, you can execute the script to build an instance of the uipanel, and use the references or tags to change the specific content on the parts/components.